# Requisição prévia para depois executar outra requisição no angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Depois que o usuário é logado na minha aplicação, todas as requisições que ele realizar deve primeiro bater em uma API que vai validar se o plano está de acordo.

Existe alguma forma de padronizar as requisições para que sempre façam essa requisição prévia e só depois realize a requisição solicitada caso o plano esteja de acordo? Ou preciso colocar requisição por requisição?

O Http injector serviria pra isso?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisas de usar um HttpInterceptor.

Para isso crias um serviço deste genero:

```
@Injector()
export class RequestInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        // adiciona o token desta forma
        // neste exemplo o token, quando existe, está guardado na localstorage
        if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
                }
            });
        }


         return next.handle(request).pipe(
            tap(
              event => { },
              error => {
                this.handleErrors(error);
              }
            ),
            finalize(() => { })
        );
    }

    private handleErrors(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
        let errorMessage: string;
        if (err.status === 0) {
            errorMessage = 'Sem ligação à internet';
        } else if (err.status === 401) { // O token expirou ou nem foi enviado. Fazer novamente autenticação. 
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        } else { // ocorreu outro erro. Mostrar mensagem ao utilizador
            errorMessage = err.error.message;
        }

        if(errorMessage) {
            // mostrar mensagem em modal, por exemplo
        }
    }
}
```

E adicionas o serviço aos providers do HTTP_INTERCEPTORS destae forma:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        // ...
    ],
    imports: [
        // ...
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: RequestInterceptorService,
            multi: true,
        }
    ],
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Isso já é o que eu faço no meu interceptor atualmente, eu preciso fazer uma requisição http prévia pra ver se o token ainda é válido, e somente se for válido colocar ele na próxima requisição

Comment: @RenatoVeronese Isso irá tornar a aplicação mais lenta. A melhor forma é deixar que o servidor responda que o token expirou. Código da resposta atualizado para este cenário.

Comment: Eu sei, mas meu chefe quer dessa forma, já expliquei que isso é feito no backend através do token mas ele quer mais uma validação

Comment: @RenatoVeronese E explicaste que por cada request feito, terás sempre um extra para validar o token, o que vai tornar o site/webapp mais lento e duplicar a carga no servidor?

A única coisa que para mim fazia algum sentido era validar a data de expiração to token. Se estiveres a usar algo como o JWT, no próprio token tens essa informação embebida. https://gist.github.com/soulmachine/b368ce7292ddd7f91c15accccc02b8df